# Unable to extract values from a dynamic list of lists in a JSON response in Power Automate

Tags: json, azure-application-insights, power-automate, jsonparser

In Power Automate, from the following json response which is obtained from azure-application-insights, I wish to extract each of the sub-lists in the “rows” list. The number of sub-lists would be variable depending upon the responses from the insights.

```
{
  "tables": [
    {
      "name": "PrimaryResult",
      "columns": [
        {
          "name": "Name",
          "type": "dynamic"
        },
        {
          "name": "Question",
          "type": "dynamic"
        },
        {
          "name": "Answer",
          "type": "dynamic"    
      ],
      "rows": [
        [
          "John",
          "when are you going",
          "January’ 2022?"
        ],
        [
          "Albert",
          "who will add deal co-owners for a deal?",
          "The authorizers"
        ],
        [
          "Mohan",
          "co-deal owner name can be added by whom?",
          "The approvers”
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I wish to dynamically extract the contents of all the sub-lists, and use each of the extracted outputs separately.

Comment: Where do you want to save those results after extraction?

Comment: @osfresia  Actually, I want to separately send data of  each of the sub-lists in a message posted in a teams channel. Separate messages for each of the sub-lists should be sent. Do you know of any way for this?

Comment: @KanwarRajSinghSandhu did you ever resolve this?